# Use of JBMP on Django Projects

Tags: django, jbpm

My company has created multiple enterprise applications over the past 15 years that now needs to gradually migrate to the web. I've created a pilot app using Django showcasing it's powers and how each legacy app can be converted.

For now the MVC architecture was the best solution proposed. Among the other architectures was a full Java stack that made use of JBPM for it's workflow management which my boss needed and asked if we could somehow make use of JBPM and preferably not some other BPM - 'cuase of it's powers.

The idea is to create multiple Django powered applications that each work on their own and then use JBPM to connect some of the Django services/views together in a workflow manner.

The question is can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not:

Django can interact with webservices -- which is what you could use in order to interact with jBPM from the Django applications, and vice versa. A quick google implied that web services were easy enough to implement in order to interact with a Django frontend (from jBPM in this case).

Comment: So each service in Django has a URL and JBPM just connects these together

Comment: if each service in Django has a URL, then I'm guessing that you could access these services using a RESTful service interface? jBPM can then "connect these together" in the sense that it can call the services in a specific order (workflow) and react to/process the results (if result service A == 2, then call service B, otherwise call service C.. etc.).